# Seminorms: Locally Convex Space

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

**Problem**

Given a vector space $\Omega$.

Consider a family of seminorms:
$$\mathcal{M}\subseteq\{\mu:V\to\mathbb{R}_+\}$$

Regard the local base:
$$\mathcal{B}_0:=\{[0,\varepsilon):\varepsilon>0\}$$

Denote the open cylinders by:
$$B_\mu(\varepsilon):=\mu^{-1}[0,\varepsilon)$$

Then it becomes a locally convex space by:
$$\mathcal{N}_0:=\mathcal{F}\left(\bigcup_{\mu\in\mathcal{M}}\mu^{-1}\mathcal{B}_0\right)$$

Moreover the seminorms become continuous:
$$\mu^{-1}\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{R}_+)\subseteq\mathcal{T}(\Omega)$$

How to prove this step by step?

**Attempt**

They set up a neighborhood system since:
$$a\in B_\mu(\varepsilon):\quad B_\mu(\varepsilon_a)+a\subseteq B_\mu(\varepsilon)\quad(\varepsilon_a:=\varepsilon-\mu(a)>0)$$

Also it is compatible with addition since:
$$\left\{B_\mu\left(\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+a\right\}+\left\{B_\mu\left(\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+b\right\}\subseteq B_\mu(\varepsilon)+(a+b)$$
But what about compatibility with multiplication?
$$$$
Moreover for the seminorms by construction:
$$\mu^{-1}\mathcal{N}_0(\mathbb{R}_+)\subseteq\mathcal{N}_0(V)\implies\mu^{-1}\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{R}_+)\subseteq\mathcal{T}(\Omega)$$
That is continuity at zero suffices!

**Reference**

This is the close-up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

Denote for shorthand:
$$d:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+:d(x):=|x|$$

It is a neighborhood system as:
$$a\in B_\mu(\varepsilon):\quad B_\mu(\varepsilon_a)+a\subseteq B_\mu(\varepsilon)\quad(\varepsilon_a:=\varepsilon-\mu(a)>0)$$

Also it is compatible with addition since:
$$\left\{B_\mu\left(\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+a\right\}+\left\{B_\mu\left(\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+b\right\}=B_\mu\left(\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+B_\mu\left(\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)+a+b\subseteq B_\mu(\varepsilon)+(a+b)$$

And similarly for multiplication since:
$$\{B_d(\delta)+\lambda\}\{B_\mu(\delta)+a\}=B_d(\delta)B_\mu(\delta)+B_d(\delta)a+\lambda B_\mu(\delta)+\lambda a\subseteq B_\mu(\varepsilon)+(\lambda a)$$

Moreover for the seminorm by construction:
$$\mu^{-1}\mathcal{N}_0(\mathbb{R}_+)\subseteq\mathcal{N}_0(V)\implies\mu^{-1}\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{R}_+)\subseteq\mathcal{T}(\Omega)$$
*(See thread on: [Continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1182724/79762))*